# Make element fill horizontal line

Tags: html, css, alignment

This is a question similar to many that have been asked before. However, with all the previous questions, the necessary widths are known. For me, the widths are unknown.

If I have two columns (primary, secondary), how would I use css such that as primary expands and contracts, secondary fills the remaining horizontal space. I would like to achieve something like the [split pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) effect, where the location of the split is dictated by the size of primary.

It is imperative to understand that I do not know how many pixels or how much width primary will take up, primary's size will increase and decrease.

It could be:

|----Primary----|----------------------------Secondary---------------------------|

Or:

|-----Primary------|----------------------------Secondary------------------------|

Or even:

|-------------------------Primary------------------------|-------Secondary-------|

How would I do this using CSS? Is it even possible to make an element provisionally "greedy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, if you're not adverse to using it, you could apply the `display:table-cell` CSS property to the columns, then use `width:100%` on the latter one. The HTML structure would look like this:

```
<div class="split-pane">
    <div>
        Left content
    </div>
    <div>
        Right content
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.split-pane > div {
    display:table-cell;
}
.split-pane > div:first-child {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.split-pane > div:last-child {
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/mD9mw/2/) to show you what this achieves. Note how as you add more text in a line on the left, it'll push the boundary to the right as needed. (The `white-space:nowrap;` is there so that the content on the left doesn't wrap on every single word.) Be advised that this CSS will not be interpreted properly on older versions of IE, if that's of concern.

If this isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further!

Comment: I really wish this worked, but it just puts `secondary` below `primary`, just like before.

Comment: Hmm, what browser are you viewing this with?

Comment: Chrome. Don't get me wrong, your JSFiddle is just fine. But my webpage is not.

Comment: Oh ah...I see, do you have any way to show the actual code you're using? I can adapt the answer to reflect the context in which you're implementing this if I get a better idea of the conditions.

Comment: Ah, I see! It's because the `display:table-cell` is cascading down to each content `<div>`'s children, which is messing it all up. Just need to use the immediate child selector, `>` to stop that from happening. I'll update my answer accordingly with better code and a JSFiddle.

Comment: It looks like that will work. Here's an even more updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/mD9mw/3/
I'll accept this answer as soon as I get my actual code working. Thank you!

Comment: All right, glad this has gotten you in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: D: Everything is (css-wise) the same as the example and it is like the browser is just messing with me. Primary and Secondary are technically aligned, but secondary just shifted below primary and filled the area above it with padding, and primary filled below with padding also. What in the heck...

Comment: Found it. Sub-element had "display:inline-block"

Answer (score 0):

It is correct you can't do this with pixels, however there are other ways to define width. I think you may want to try using % rather than px in your css.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the 'sencondary' div doesn't matter, you can make some css like this:

```
#primary    { position: absolute;
            z-index: 1; }
#secondary  { position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 0; }
```

If there is content that needs to be moved dynamically, you can move the secondary div easily with jQuery. Here's a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/LZJZU/5/